Getting new_app_user event logged automatically in Firebase Analytics version 10.25.0
I have integrated the firebase analytics in the iOS app with version of Firebase Analytics 10.25.0.
Here when ever any event got logged the new_app_user event which we have not added in the code of our app, on search in project it is no where in app is getting logged in debug_view of the Firebase console.
Reproducing the issue
Every time when I am checking events log in debug_view it is logging event automatically with name new_app_user.
Tried to search custom events on firebase, there was nothing related to this.
In app code there nothing related to this,searched for that even in other libraries used.
Expecting:-
There should be no new_app_user event when we are logging other events of the Firebase in app.
